# Which methods can a subclass inherit in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

Sorry I am a newbie to Java. I am trying to get my head around inheritance and subclass/superclass relationships in Java.

If classA is a subclass of classB, will classA's protocol feature all methods that belong to classA or only those declared public and package?

Can classA's protocol feature private methods inherited from its superclass ClassB?

Comment: Common mistake in answers, except for Bohemian's. Even privates **are inherited** - they are just not **available** to subclass code. But they are still there and work, if called from ancestor methods.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, the word "inherited" isn't quite the right term. You mean "visible".

- `public` and `protected` are always visible
- `private` is not visible
- default (a.k.a. "package") visibility - ie no specified visibility - is visible only if the subclass is in the same package (as it be would for *any* class in the same package)

Answer (score 1):

All public and protected methods and variables will be inherited. Any methods with the same signature in the subclass will override the superclass behavior. The subclass will not inherit private methods and variables. Default (a.k.a package visibility level) will be inherited if in the same pacakge and by subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

ClassA will inherit all of classB's public and protected methods. It will NOT include classB's private methods.

Comment: What about default visibility?

Comment: Default visibility is private.

Comment: default visibility is (surprise!) default

Answer (score 0):

ClassB's private methods are not visible to ClassA. If you want to give ClassA access to internal methods of ClassB (without those methods becoming part of ClassB's public interface) you should make them protected instead of private.

Answer (score 0):

Public methods, labeled by `public` are available to every class.
Protected methods, labeled by `protected` are available to subclasses and friendly classes, which are classes in the same package.
Friendly methods, labeled by nothing (i.e. default) are available to friendly classes.
Private methods are available only to the class itself.

Static methods, labeled by `static` are available to without an object to access them. These are called by ClassName.foo(), SuperClassName.foo() (unnecessary if not overriden, foo() is acceptable), or ClassName.foo() (unnecessary, foo() is acceptable)
Dynamic (check vocab???) labeled by nothing (i.e. default) are available only if one has an object of the class. ex: bar.foo(), this.foo() (unnecessary, foo() is acceptable), or super.foo() (unnecessary if not overridden, foo() is acceptable)
Overriden methods, annotated by `@Override` are only available through `super.foo`

So in an instance of ClassB, all `protected` and `public` members and methods of ClassA will be accessible. In a static call, only static methods are accessible.

Answer (score -1):

Private methods are not inherited.  Only protected, public and default methods are inherited.

Class A will provide the methods that are public in both classA and ClassB

Comment: Wrong! Default are not inherited. Any class from the same package can see default visibility methods. If the subclass is in the same package, then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: ClassA can use ClassB's default methods only if they are in the same package.